# Hatch each bar separately in matplotlib

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, plot, bar-chart

I have a barchart consisting of 7 bars, I want to hatch each bar separately. My attempt was to create a list and assign it to the hatch attribute as below:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
fig, ((ax1, ax2), (ax3, ax4)) = plt.subplots(2, 2,figsize=(15,15))
fig.suptitle('Sharing x per column, y per row')
y_ax1 = [-1.2,0.9,0.2,-4,-3.8,-3.7,-5]
hatch=['*','+','|','|','*','*','*']
x_ax1= [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
ax1.bar(x_ax1,y_ax1, color=['blue', 'blue', 'blue', 'maroon', 'maroon','maroon','maroon'],hatch=hatch)
ax1.set_ylim(-6, 1)
ax1.set_yticks(np.arange(-5,2,1))
ax1.axhline(y=0, color='g', linestyle='-')
for ax in fig.get_axes():
    ax.label_outer()
```

I tried to follow the [docs](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/shapes_and_collections/hatch_demo.html), but I am getting the following error in my colab [colab link](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1pHmMB9EArEFj8hKrGTXWYquh16DLsjht?usp=sharing):

```
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

Comment: When I run your example, I have to add a closing bracket for the `hatch` kwargs in `.bar`. After that, the example runs

Comment: @PaulH I added the ] at the end, still doesn't work

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/exILY.png. Unable to reproduce.

Comment: @BigBen Please check my colab link: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1pHmMB9EArEFj8hKrGTXWYquh16DLsjht?usp=sharing

Comment: [Upgrade your version of matplotlib](https://matplotlib.org/3.5.1/users/prev_whats_new/whats_new_3.4.0.html#a-list-of-hatches-can-be-specified-to-bar-and-barh).